# Direct3D Shader Internal Compiler Error X8000: Invalid Bytecode

Tags: direct3d, hlsl

When compiling this simple pixel shader:

```
Texture2D tex0 : register(t0);
Texture2D tex1 : register(t1);

SamplerState s : register(s0);

float4 main(float2 tc : TEXCOORD0) : SV_TARGET
{
    Texture2D tex = tex0;
    if (tc.x > 0.5)
    {
        tex = tex1;
    }
    return tex.SampleLevel(s, tc, 0);
}
```

Using the command line `fxc.exe /T ps_4_0 hello.hlsl` I get:

```
Microsoft (R) Direct3D Shader Compiler 10.1 (using C:\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86\D3DCOMPILER_47.dll)
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

error X8000: D3D11 Internal Compiler Error: Invalid Bytecode: Invalid operand type for operand #3 of opcode #8 (counts are 1-based).
error X8000: D3D11 Internal Compiler Error: Invalid Bytecode: Can't continue validation - aborting.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal compiler error is not a helpful error here, but the pattern you used above is just not something most people write. The same shader works if you write it as:

```
Texture2D tex0 : register(t0);
Texture2D tex1 : register(t1);

SamplerState s : register(s0);

float4 main(float2 tc : TEXCOORD0) : SV_TARGET
{
    if (tc.x > 0.5)
    {
        return tex1.SampleLevel(s, tc, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        return tex0.SampleLevel(s, tc, 0);
    }
}
```

Note that the [DXIL](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler) compiler for Shader Model 6 returns a more sensible error in this case:

> error: local resource not guaranteed to map to unique global resource. Use /Zi for source location.